# Cronjob with wp_insert_post() not working

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have developed a Wordpress plugin that retrieves emails through an IMAP connection and publishes them in Wordpress using the wp_insert_post() function. The function works fine when called manually, but when run through a cron job, it doesn't publish the post. I suspect the wp_insert_post() function doesn't work due to insufficient privileges of the cron job. How can I grant this cron job sufficient privileges to execute the wp_insert_post() function?

```php
//PART OF THE FUNCTION!
// Create new WordPress post
$post = array(
    'post_title' => $header->subject,
    'post_content' => wpautop($body),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => $author_id,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_category' => array($category_id)
);

// Save post to WordPress
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post);

// Check if the post was successfully saved to WordPress
if (!is_wp_error($post_id)) {

    // Mark email read after successful processing
    imap_setflag_full($imap_connection, $mail, "\\Seen");

} else {

    // The post could not be saved to WordPress
    $error_message = 'An error occurred while posting the email message to WordPress.';

    if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {
        $error_message .= ' Error message: ' . $post_id->get_error_message();
    }
    error_log($error_message);
}

// Check for post saving errors
if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {
    die('An error occurred while saving the post.');
}
}

// Close IMAP server connection
imap_close($imap_connection);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the error message logged?

Comment: No, the respons from if (!is_wp_error($post_id)) is clean, so the message is set to \\Seen but the mail is not posted. There is no error in the logs.